# My Android Ribbon app build succesfully but fail to run

Tags: java, android

My Android Ribbon app keeps crushing with successful build but when I go to run it shows me this:

> 05/15 16:36:44: Launching app No apk changes detected since last
>   installation, skipping installation of
>   C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\AndroidRibbon\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>   $ adb shell am force-stop com.example.asus.androidribbon $ adb shell
>   am start -n
>   "com.example.asus.androidribbon/com.example.asus.androidribbon.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online Waiting for
>   process to come online

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild?, do a clean and then build.

Comment: i've already done that. still doesn't work